# hash table : how to achieve 0(1)?

Tags: c, hash, time-complexity

### Context :

I was reading Pomakis' hash table implementation and one question arised.
[Hash lookup](http://www.pomakis.com/hashtable/hashtable.h)

I used Startpage a lot to find additional info but still in the blur.

### Question :

How is it possible to get 0(1) time complexity since it uses a linked list to retrieve the key?

### Problem :

The structure :

```
typedef struct KeyValuePair_struct {
    const void *key;
    void *value;
    struct KeyValuePair_struct *next;
} KeyValuePair;
```

To me, it looks like a linked list. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
void *HashTableGet(const HashTable *hashTable, const void *key) {
    long hashValue = hashTable->hashFunction(key) % hashTable->numOfBuckets;
    KeyValuePair *pair = hashTable->bucketArray[hashValue];

    while (pair != NULL && hashTable->keycmp(key, pair->key) != 0)
        pair = pair->next;

    return (pair == NULL)? NULL : pair->value;
}
```

I read everywhere that to get a key, we have to iterate from the beginning of the struct chain up to the right structure, because we don't know in advance the address of the next structure.

<=> Dynamic allocation.

So I don't get the point : the latter piece of code seems to iteratefrom the beginning of the chain, but the author says it is O(1) (and he may be right and I am surely wrong about my asumption that it is 0(n) ).

I know I miss something. But what ?

Thanks

Comment: It's `O(1)` to get to the *bucket*, but a bucket may have several entries. The lookup within the bucket is linear, yes. When the number of buckets is large enough and if the elements are evenly distributed, it is equivalent to `O(1)`. In a pathological case where only one bucket is used, it is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function HashTableGet() will first get its KeyValuePair from the array

```
KeyValuePair *pair = hashTable->bucketArray[hashValue];
```

This operation is O(1)

The next pointer is only used in case of a different key produces the same hashvalue when adding a new KeyValuePair . Then the next pointer is used to store that KeyValuePair in the list.

When retrieving, if the key doesn't match the first KeyValuePair key then a search through the list is required.

```
while (pair != NULL && hashTable->keycmp(key, pair->key) != 0)
    pair = pair->next;
```

Comment: Ok ! so in best case it is 0(1) and in the worst 0(1) + 0(n), right ? Hence the importance of a good hash to minimise the linear lookup in case of a dup. Right ?

Comment: Yes, and the size of bucketArray also matters.